# Which event fires after all items are loaded and shown in a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, events

Which event fires after all items are loaded and shown in a WPF ListView?
I try to optimize showing lots of Items in a ListView. The ListView is populated with Items with the following code:

```
List<Artist> selectedArtistsList;
//Code to fill selectedArtistsList with about 6,000 items not shown here
CollectionViewSource selection1ViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("selection1Source")));
Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch1.Start();
selection1ViewSource.Source = selectedArtistsList;
stopWatch1.Stop();
Debug.Print("Time used: {0}ms", stopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

When I run this code I see "Time used 119ms" or something similar. But then it takes about 3 seconds more before I see the Items in the ListView on the screen. 
Is there an event which fires after the ListView is loaded with the Items?
I am interested to measure when the ListView looks ready for the user.

Comment: Try `listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged`. WPF renders on a separate thread, so if you want to run code after rendering is complete you could try Dispatcher.Invoke with a priority < Render

Comment: If that is taking 3 second then you might not be virtualizing.  Post your XAML.

Comment: Thanks @Blam, I will check about virtualizing. Now, after I know how to check exactly how long it takes to show my list, it will be easier for me to compare different ways to improve my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I found a solution.
After Nick Baker’s comment I googled Dispatcher.Invoke. After reading and testing I found this page

WPF: Running code when Window rendering is completed
http://geekswithblogs.net/ilich/archive/2012/10/16/running-code-when-windows-rendering-is-completed.aspx

Then I changed my code to the following (not the complete code, just the relevant parts):

```
private void Work(){
    List<Artist> selectedArtistsList;
    //Code to fill selectedArtistsList with about 6,000 items not shown here
    CollectionViewSource selection1ViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("selection1Source")));
    stopWatch1.Reset();
    stopWatch1.Start();
    selection1ViewSource.Source = selectedArtistsList;
    Debug.Print("After setting Source: {0}ms", stopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

    //New:
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(RenderingDone), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
}

//New
Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
private void RenderingDone() {
    Debug.Print("After rendering is done: {0}ms", stopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

After running this I see:
After setting Source: 124ms
After rendering is done: 2273ms

The last line appear after the rendering is done and it shows the correct time. This is exactly what I wanted.