# Datagrid binding completed event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, loading

Is there a good way to raise an event when datagrid binding event completed. The problem is that some rows takes a lot of time for loading. Therefore, I want to show a image/process message during loading.

Comment: The problem is, I need to know exact time when rows are loaded.

Comment: there must be an event that fires the load event, in that load event as soon as it fires create a programatic progress bar

Comment: There is nothing to do with progressbar !

Comment: I am only interested in event. I know how to use a progressbar ! The problem is we don't know when data is loaded.

Comment: @Ugur: you don't need an event. You need asynchronously loaded data. There are many articles/blog posts over internet about this. One of them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hey @Dennis, I am loading data already asynchronously. The problem occurs only during binding due to too many columns and rows. It takes time to create all rows and columns.

Comment: Most of WPF items controls use virtualization, hence, don't create all rows immediately. I don't know which one are you using, but the problem is elsewhere. You've mentioned many columns - how much is this "many"? If you're trying to display some grid data with, say, 100 columns, than you definitely should revise approach.

Comment: @Dennis, thanks for the advise. I am loading more than 120 rows at the same time. Of course data grid losses its smoothness. You are right. I can revise my approach. Even in that case, there should be some event that will say "just wait I am rendering the views, rows etc. Maybe it will take time and I will inform you" :).   However, thanks in advance. I will also look for alternative approaches

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729881/which-event-fires-after-all-items-are-loaded-and-shown-in-a-listview basically, if you place an action with appropriate priority in the dispatcher after the loading started, the action should execute after the loading completed

Comment: @grek40, yes, i think so, it may help. Thanks!